# Get entries whose title has a keyword or related to a category's title

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I am trying to get entries that either their title has the keyword or their category field title. I am getting them from my plugin, not twig.
I tried like this:

```
$keywordCategory= Category::find()->title($keyword)->all();
$entries = Entry::find()->title($keyword)->relatedTo($keywordCategory)->all();
```

but it must be in the title and the category field. Is there a way to check using where and orWhere?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to create the `relatedTo` condition manually first and then pass it in to the `orWhere` method. This is untested, but should get you on the right track.

Reference the `_applyRelatedToParam()` method in the `ElementQuery` class:
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/3.1.26/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php#L1724-L1727

```
$keywordCategory = Category::find()->title($keyword)->all();

$parser = new ElementRelationParamParser();
$relatedTo = $parser->parse($keywordCategory);

$entries = Entry::find()
    ->where(['title' => $keyword])
    ->orWhere($relatedTo)
    ->all();
```