# Relations query with OR: Find entries based on (lightswitch = false AND relatedTo()) OR (lightswitch = true) / nested relatedTo?

Tags: database, query, relatedto, sql

I have the following challenge:

- we have a news channel for multiple company locations.
- Some news should be visible globally (for all locations), but some news are only visible for location X.

But when a visitor visits **location-x**.company.com/news/, both news entries should be visible:

- **news that are visible globally**
- **OR**
- **news that aren't visible globally, but have specific location X in
  the entries field**

I have two fields in a channel:

- Checkbox "Visible everywhere"? - yes / no

[image: checkbox]

- If "Visible everyhwere" == false, an Entries Field is shown "Visible in locations: []"

[image: checkbox false, another field shown - entries field]

**How can I generate a query in PHP for that?**

I tried this, but it does not work - orWhere is ignored and it just ends up as "AND" in the SQL query.

```php
$query->relatedTo(['targetElement' => $locationId, 'field' => 'visibleInLocations']);

$query->orWhere(['isVisibleInAllLocations' => true]);
```

The following does not work either ("Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'relatedTo' in 'where clause'")

```php
$query->andWhere([
    'or',
    ['relatedTo' => ['targetElement' => $locationId, 'field' => 'visibleInLocations']],
    ['isVisibleInAllLocations' => true],
]);
```

I made complex queries before, but not with relatedTo:

```php
 $query->andWhere([
              'or',
              [
                  // for normal entries
                  'and',
                  ['=', $isProjectColumnName, 0],
                  ['>=', $minPriceColumn, $minPrice],
                  ['<=', $maxPriceColumn, $maxPrice],
              ],
              [
                  // for special project entries
                  'and',
                  ['=', $isProjectColumnName, 1],
                  // other fields for comparision
                  ['>=', $minPriceColumnForProjects, $minPrice],
                  ['<=', $minPriceColumnForProjects, $maxPrice],
              ]
          ]);
```

Has anybody solved this yet?

Thanks very much in advance for any hints!

(I searched almost everywhere, only found issues about chaining relatedTo or this quick hint https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/30348 - but don't know if this would be the easiest approach for my use case)

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this in Twig this week. My query ended up looking like this based on the [craft cms docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter).

```
{% set query = craft.entries()
   .section('news')
   .search('isVisibleInAllLocations::true OR visibleInLocations:locationSlug)
   .status('live')
   .orderBy('postDate DESC')
   .all() 
%}
```

Please note I am using the search method for this, allowing me to pass parameters that either contain or match exactly. The `::` means the field contains the exact value, and `:` means it contains part of that value. You can also use `score` as an orderBy in this case due to the usage of the search parameter, but news feeds tend to be most recent first.

I believe you would transfer the above Twig into the following PHP, please note that I haven't transfer Twig into PHP in a while

```
$query = Entry::find()
    ->section('news')
    ->search('isVisibleInAllLocations::true OR visibleInLocations:locationSlug')
    ->status('live')
    ->orderBy('postDate DESC')
    ->all();
```

I hope you find this helpful! Interested to know if this works for you or if you have an alternate solution.